# How to make Custom Input Mask to allow specific website in wp-form wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, input-mask, wpforms

I have a wp-form with a website/url label, and I want user to insert URL's that end on .au only. I can't find the proper regex or format for input mask. User can input any form of character, letter or number in URL as long as it end on .au

[image]